# I cant open a popup for a specific div in while loop (Javascript PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I clicked the div with id `ooo` no his specific div with id `row['user_name']` won't popup

```
 <!-- this code is inside a while loop -->

 <div id="ooo"  onclick="testado('.$row['usr_name'].')" class="link dropdown">
<h5 class="text-left" >'.$row['usr_name'].'</h5>
<img src="crownh.png"  class="float-right"  />
```

```
<div id="'.$row['usr_name'].'" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div ><span class="close">&times;</span>
<p> '.$row['usr_name'].'</p> </div> </div>


</div>


<!-- this is the javascript -->

 function testado(a) { // This function gets called when clicking the button
        var modal = document.getElementById(a);
                modal.style.display = "block";

}
```

Thanks

Comment: you're calling the element wrong, just append something on the id like `ooo-<username here>`, then provide the function argument as `ooo-<username here>`

Comment: @Ghost no sir , i don't wanna call the div with id ooo    , i want to call the one with id username

Comment: he's giving you an example @HassanElkhalifte

Comment: the id in order to call it would have to be something like `ooo-2` or `ooo-3` or `ooo-username1` or `ooo-username2`

Comment: @JeanPaul98 it wont work for me maybe because , when  i call the javascript , it cant access to the while again

Comment: place the JS inside the while loop

Comment: @JeanPaul98 Okey i'll Try it now

Comment: is that your full JS script?

Comment: @JeanPaul98 yeah it is

Comment: Your code is so confusing my friend

Comment: @JeanPaul98 Yah lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/7w34fnp3/1/

I think the issue is simply some missing apostrophes in the first `div`. Try this:

```
<div id="ooo" class="link dropdown" onclick="testado(\''.$row['usr_name'].'\')">
  <h5 class="text-left">'.$row['usr_name'].'</h5>
  <img src="crownh.png" class="float-right" />
  <div id="'.$row['usr_name'].'" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div><span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>'.$row['usr_name'].'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assume this is because you are echoing this output with a single quote (`echo '<...'`) and you're doing `onclick="testado(matt)"` instead of `onclick="testado('matt')"`.

There are lots of more efficient ways to do this code with an onClick listener instead of the onclick event. jQuery helps here. You should also name the `ooo` div dynamically as you're currently creating a load of divs with the same id.

Also you should practise indenting your code to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Wooooooooooooow , Worked Fiiiiiiine , As i Really Want , Thaaaanks To You //Solved